# Extract character from a sting based on char index modulo 12==0 Python

Tags: python, indexing, modulo

I'm learning modulo(%) for python and want to do the following:

> Extract character from string if character index % 12==0.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you mean you need to extract every 12th character from a string?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to extract every 12'th character from string `s` would be to "slice": `s[::12]`. But it won't help you in learning about `%`. But if you want to use it, you need to enumerate the characters and then filter based on the condition:

```
"".join([x for (i,x) in enumerate(s) if i % 12==0])
```